# PHP- Loop through multidimensional array and reduce arrays if key found

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like this:

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:5 [
    "id" => 18
    "product_id" => 37
    "total_price" => "643.00"
    "created_at" => "2017-05-02 13:22:35"
    "updated_at" => "2017-05-02 13:22:35"
  ]
  1 => array:5 [
    "id" => 19
    "product_id" => 36
    "total_price" => "532.00"
    "created_at" => "2017-05-02 13:23:47"
    "updated_at" => "2017-05-02 13:23:47"
  ]
  2 => array:5 [
    "id" => 20
    "product_id" => 36
    "total_price" => "532.00"
    "created_at" => "2017-05-03 13:20:47"
    "updated_at" => "2017-05-03 13:20:47"
  ]
]
```

In my case if the key "product_id" has the same value I want to reduce merge those arrays and add the total_price but I have to also save a new key to the new array: $quantity to store the number of array with the same key that existed before merging.
So the final result should look like this:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:5 [
    "id" => 18
    "product_id" => 37
    "total_price" => "643.00"
    "quantity"   => 1
    "created_at" => "2017-05-02 13:22:35"
    "updated_at" => "2017-05-02 13:22:35"
  ]
  1 => array:5 [
    "id" => 19
    "product_id" => 36
    "total_price" => "1064.00"
    "quantity"   => 2
    "created_at" => "2017-05-02 13:23:47"
    "updated_at" => "2017-05-02 13:23:47"
  ]
]
```

Initially I tried with array_walk_recursive, but I got confused.

```
array_walk_recursive($products, function($value, $key) use (&$products_sold){
            array_push($products_sold, isset($products_sold[$key]) ?  $value + $products_sold[$key] : $value);
        });
```

I know this is useless but I failed to realize how to do this. Any explanation would be helpful.
Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$result = array_reduce($products, function ($result, $product) {
    foreach ($result as $index => $value) {
        if ($value['product_id'] == $product['product_id']) {
            $result[$index]['total_price'] += $product['total_price'];

            return $result;
        }
    }
    $result[] = $product;
    return $result;
}, []);
```

But I strongly recomment use [BCMath](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) functions instead of working with floats.

So its better to write

```
$result[$index]['total_price'] = bcadd($result[$index]['total_price'], $product['total_price'], 2);
```

instead of

```
$result[$index]['total_price'] += $product['total_price'];
```

---

**Update**

We can rewrite above version to nested foreach like so:

```
$reducer = function ($result, $product) {
    foreach ($result as $index => $value) {
        if ($value['product_id'] == $product['product_id']) {
            $result[$index]['total_price'] += $product['total_price'];

            return $result;
        }
    }
    $result[] = $product;
    return $result;
};

$result = [];

foreach($products as $product) {
    $result = $reducer($result, $product);
}
```

so we can see it is just foreach loop which calls function which contains another foreach.
We need another foreach because we need the way to determine if array contains product_id.
We can index result with product_id so we can avoid secind foreach:

```
$result = array_reduce($products, function ($result, $product) {
    $productId = $product['product_id'];
    if(isset($result[$productId])) {
        $result[$productId]['total_price'] += $product['total_price'];
        return $result;
    }
    $result[$productId] = $product;
    return $result;
}, []);
```

and then if you need indexes to be ordered from zero just call `array_values($result)`

Comment: sadly I get: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() @Nikita

Comment: little fix added :)

Comment: It works perffectly now, thank you! But can you explain to me a bit the part with result please? I mean you make result equal with the array_reduce(which return the products reduced?) and inside of it you loop through $result...that's the part that I don't get.

Answer (score 2):

Got it done! I should say I didnt use `total_price` as `string` so I can do addition.

```
$stuff = array(
    array(
        "id" => 18,
        "product_id" => 37,
        "total_price" => 643.00,
        "created_at" => "2017-05-02 13:22:35",
        "updated_at" => "2017-05-02 13:22:35"),

    array(
        "id" => 19,
        "product_id" => 36,
        "total_price" => 532.00,
        "created_at" => "2017-05-02 13:23:47",
        "updated_at" => "2017-05-02 13:23:47"),

    array(
        "id" => 20,
        "product_id" => 36,
        "total_price" => 532.00,
        "created_at" => "2017-05-03 13:20:47",
        "updated_at" => "2017-05-03 13:20:47")
    );

for ($i=0; $i < count($stuff); $i++) { 
    $product_id = $stuff[$i]["product_id"];
    foreach ($stuff as $key => $value) {
        if($value["product_id"] === $product_id && $i !== $key) {
            $stuff[$i]["total_price"] += $value["total_price"];
            unset($stuff[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Undefined offset: 2..that is for the $product_id apparently while looping it gets out of bounds

Comment: Huh this works for me and I cant see why you should get out of bounds...

Comment: I don't think `intval` is safe to use here, because you'll lose cents

Comment: @NikitaU. Yeah I dont even use it anymore because in his example `total_price` is a `string` thats why I used `intval` but now that I use number for `total_price`, I can remove `intval`.